# Xmonad, how to bind a key to running a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, window-managers, xmonad

I'm new to xmonad. Is it possible to run a shell script  (say ~/x.sh) every time you click, for example, f1? How does that look in a config file? I have googled quite a bit now without finding anything that looks like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xev` to determine the keysym of your `F1`-key, which is on my system `0xffbe`, and add

```
myKeys = [ ((0, 0xffbe), spawn "/path/to/x.sh") ]
```

to your `xmonad.hs`. As described in [XMonad.Util.EZConfig](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html), use

```
`additionalKeys` myKeys
```

in your `main` function, and recompile+restart. Probably it also works with `additionalKeysP` and `<F1>`, but i haven't tested that - the link above has all infos.

Comment: From the `EZConfig` module documentation you linked, you can click on `KeySym` in your function's type to get [the definition of the `KeySym` type and the list of defined variable names for the keys](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/X11/Graphics-X11-Types.html#t:KeySym) : xK_F1

Comment: Following on from Leiaz's comment, you should be able to write something like `main =
       xmonad $ desktopConfig \`additionalKeys\`
            [ ((0,                      xK_F1), spawn "/path/to/x.sh")
            ...
            ]`